# Android ImageView shape lost when image set

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-shape

I'm using the ImageView with custom shape (it works well) but lost once an image is set to that ImageView.

My ImageView:

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custome_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

and the custom shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/buttonColorEnabled" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/buttonColorDefault" />
</selector>
```

Is there a way to preserve the ImageView shape when assigning a new image to the same? Thanks.

Comment: In your case, you can achieve that by setting padding on your `ImageView`. why you have set `height` on your Shape?

Comment: updated the custom shape, the padding didn't help. Thanks.